# How to apply the pivot system in a matrix reduction

Tags: matrices

\begin{align}
4x_2 + 8x_3 &= 9 &(1)\\
0.1x_1 + 2x_2 + 9x_3 &= 10 &(2)\\
155x_1 + 2x_2 -7x_3 &= 0.001 &(3)
\end{align}
Which equations would I swap to use the pivot method when reducing this?

Comment: What does pivoting accomplish? What is the usual objective in pivoting?

Comment: Why don't you show some of your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- You find the item in column $1$ with largest absolute magnitude
- Make that the first row by swapping those rows
- Divide that new first row by that magnitude
- Use that new first row to get zeros in the remaining two positions in the first row
- Repeat this process for column $2$
- Solve the remaining system

You should get an augmented matrix that looks like:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.0129032 & -0.0451613 & 6.45161 \times 10^{-6} \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 9/4 \\ 0 & 0 & 5.0071 & 5.5029 \end{bmatrix}$$

This will result in:

$$x_1 = 0.0489692, x_2 = 0.05196, x_3 = 1.09902$$

Comment: - needs a TU! +1

Comment: My pleasure. Good morning to you, as well!